# IreportServer tie a local folder into the report server

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

Here is what I want to do. I have a large collection of jasper reports, compiled and ready to go. 
Now I have setup jasperserver on my dev machine. And I want to know if there is an easy way to tie my local reports to jasperserver. So if I do an hg pull and update they will automagically get updated on jasperserver. Is this possible? I have seen you can import and export but that looks like a less than Ideal solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JasperReports Server (formerly known as JasperServer) is designed to handle .jrxml files, not .jasper files. It compiles the jrxmls into jaspers automatically.

There's no automated way to upload a bunch of reports like you're describing. But there are web services available to upload reports. So you could create a job that uses these web services to upload your reports however you want. The end result should be exactly what you want, but it will take some coding. The web services documentation ships with the server.